# C After filling buffers with data, strange data appear

Tags: c, buffer, signal-processing, stm32, cmsis

Buy debugging through SWD on STM32F746NG and putting break point in last line of the code below:

```
uint16_t data[128];
q15_t ref[64];
q15_t in[64];
.
.
.
for(uint16_t ii=0;ii!=63;ii++)
  {
    ref[ii]=data[ii*2+1];
    in[ii]=data[ii*2+1];
  }


  // 3.LMS processing
    arm_lms_q15(
            &myLMS,
            in,
            ref,
            dummyOut,
            error,
            nsamples
            );

  // 4.Visualizing errors
for(uint16_t bytecount=0;bytecount!=64;bytecount++)
```

Obviously all elemnt of `ref` and `in` must be the same but the last elemnt of these are not the same. the last element of `data` is 2617 bu is -15581 on `ref` and 2409 on `in`.
The question is how to remove this data corruption in last element?

Comment: `for(uint16_t ii=0;ii!=63;ii++)` - you should be looping to `ii!=64`.

Comment: Will you answer or question removing? @KenY-N And thank you kindly.

Comment: Side note: the idiomatic way for accessing all values of an array sequencially is: `for (i = 0; i < sizeofyourarray; i++)` instead of `for (i = 0; i != sizeofyourarray; i++)`

Comment: @Jabberwocky My idea is that comparation of identicallity is easier than smaller bigger comparision for processor maybe, doesn't it?

Comment: Most modern CPU architectures will provide instructions for `less than`, `less or equal` as well as for `equal`. No need to worry about such details unless you hit some critical situation where the generated code really differs. Modern compilers are quite good at optimizing loop.

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd don't worry about such details, the difference (if any) will be minute.

Comment: It makes no difference to the processor but is a more robust style, preventing a "run-away" program.

Comment: Does Thumb-2 RISC ISA also support this feature? @Gerhardh

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd "My idea is that comparation of identicallity is easier than smaller bigger comparision for processor maybe"  This is C code, so it's the C compiler's job to pick the appropriate machine code instruction. When I compiled the answer below on ARM-none-eabi gcc 10.2.1 I get a `cmp` instruction no matter if I use `<` or `!=`. So all that `!=` achieves is a potential for off-by-one bugs.

Comment: Where it can make a difference with some processors is when counting the loop control downwards. An `i > 1` would need an instruction to specifically make the comparison before branching, but `i > 0` can sometimes be done as a side-effect of the decrement, or with a dedicated looping instruction. But it's C, so don't worry about micro optimisations as stated.

Comment: As I mentioned, if you really hit a critical situation, check the generated code and see if there is a difference at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always write loops as simple as possible. `for(uint16_t ii=0;ii!=63;ii++)` has a weird name `ii` for no reason. `i` stands for iterator, what does `ii` stand for? Also it checks `!= 63` for no reason.

An idiomatic for loop is written as `for(uint16_t i=0; i<n; i++)` and deviating from that form is often "code smell".

You should have

```
#define REF_MAX 64  // replace this with some meaningful name.
...

// remove magic numbers:
uint16_t data[REF_MAX*2];
q15_t ref [REF_MAX];
q15_t in  [REF_MAX];

// idiomatic for loop without magic numbers:
for(uint16_t i=0; i<REF_MAX; i++)
{
  ref[i] = data[i*2+1];
  in[i]  = data[i*2+1];
}
```

Now the highest index access of `ref` and `in` will be 63 (the 64th item) and the highest index acess of `data` will be `63*2 + 1 = 127` (the 128th item).

---

Unrelated to your issue, it's not a good idea to allocate large arrays like this on the stack when coding for microcontroller embedded systems. You then get a stack peak use of >256 bytes when this function is called, which is very dangerous. Declare these buffers as `static` so they end up in `.bss` instead of the stack.

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd the `ii!=63` is also using a *different* 'magic number' that should be related to the `64` already used to define the array. That makes program maintenance that much more difficult, especially when the hard coded numbers are used in other, but unrelated, contexts... *"is that 7 a 'loop 7' or a 'bitcount 7'?"*

Comment: The `ii` is because the outer loop uses `i`.

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd Okay. The most common (but also irrationally picked) name for the loop iterator of an inner loop is `j`.

Comment: i, j, k, l, m, ... ? is there any reference that contain coders tradition?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd Not as far as I know, though `i` and `j` were already present as far back as in K&R 1st edition (as were a lot of other names). I suspect that this naming tradition is older than C itself.

Comment: I want to learn about that stack peak, why dangerous, where to find that?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd The stack size on a microcontroller could be anything from <100 bytes up to many kb or even Mb in high end systems. How a stack works and how one gets stack overflows is basic computer engineering - I think I first learnt it from introductory classes to microcontrollers and embedded systems back in uni. It is apparently considered common enough knowledge to name this very site after it.